# Access certain array that has a certain value in it's name

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables

I'm trying to make a html [Sudoku](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+sudoku&oq=what+is+sudoku&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i57j69i60l2j69i65.1949j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) gameboard that loads a different puzzle depending on the php `$_GET['level']` and `$_GET['puzzle']` values. Php variables `$get_level` and `$get_puzzle` are set to the `$_GET` values so they can be used in the javascript.

```
<?php
$default_level = 'medium';
$default_puzzle = 1;
$number_of_puzzles_per_level = 10;
if (isset($_GET['level']) && isset($_GET['puzzle'])) {
    if ($_GET['level'] == 'easy' || $_GET['level'] == 'medium' || $_GET['level'] == 'hard') {
        $get_level = $_GET['level'];
    } else {
        $get_level = $default_level;
    }
    if (is_int($_GET['puzzle'])) {
        if ($_GET['puzzle'] > 0 && $_GET['puzzle'] <= $number_of_puzzles_per_level) {
            $get_puzzle = $_GET['puzzle'];
        } else {
            $get_puzzle = $default_puzzle;
        }
    } else {
        $get_puzzle = $default_puzzle;
    }
} else {
    $get_level = $default_level;
    $get_puzzle = $default_puzzle;
}
?>
```

In the javascript, I have a bunch of arrays:

```
level_easy_puzzle_1 = [[0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9], [1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 8, 0], [0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1], [7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0], [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]];
//I will fill out the rest of the puzzles later
level_easy_puzzle_2 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_easy_puzzle_3 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_easy_puzzle_4 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_easy_puzzle_5 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_easy_puzzle_6 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_easy_puzzle_7 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_easy_puzzle_8 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_easy_puzzle_9 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_easy_puzzle_10 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_medium_puzzle_1 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_medium_puzzle_2 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_medium_puzzle_3 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_medium_puzzle_4 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_medium_puzzle_5 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_medium_puzzle_6 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_medium_puzzle_7 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_medium_puzzle_8 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_medium_puzzle_9 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_medium_puzzle_10 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_hard_puzzle_1 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_hard_puzzle_2 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_hard_puzzle_3 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_hard_puzzle_4 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_hard_puzzle_5 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_hard_puzzle_6 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_hard_puzzle_7 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_hard_puzzle_8 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_hard_puzzle_9 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
level_hard_puzzle_10 = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
```

Then, I want the javascript variable `puzzle` to be set to one of the puzzle arrays above depending on the values of the below variables `get_level` and `get_puzzle`.

```
var get_level = '<?php echo $get_level; ?>';
var get_puzzle = <?php echo $get_puzzle; ?>;
```

So, if `get_level` equals `'hard'` and `get_puzzle` equals `3`, I want a variable `puzzle` to equal the contents of the array `level_hard_puzzle_3`.

```
//Here's what I have right now, but it only gives me the name of the array not the contents
var puzzle = 'level_'+get_level+'_puzzle_'+get_puzzle;
```

Hope it is clear what I want, and thanks for any help.

Comment: To use dynamic variable names you must use either *eval* or the *Function* constructor, neither are particularly liked. The usual best solution is to use object properties and square bracket notation for access, such as: `var puzzle = {}; puzzel['level_'+get_level+'_puzzle_'+get_puzzle] = somevalule;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could organize this into an object instead. Also, let array indexing take care of your numbering rather than assigning numbers to variable names. (If you decide to remove a puzzle, you'd have to rename all of them.)

```
var puzzles = {
    easy: [
            [//Puzzle 0
              [0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9],
              [1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
              [0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 8, 0],
              [0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1],
              [7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]
            ],
            [//Puzzle 1
              [0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9],
              [1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
              [0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 8, 0],
              [0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1],
              [7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]
            ]
    ], //end of the easy puzzles
    medium: [], //...and so on...
    hard: [],
}
```

I suggest making a function to retrieve puzzles, so you can control your logic neatly in one place:

```
function getPuzzle(difficulty, level){
    if(puzzles[difficulty] && puzzles[difficulty].length >= level -1){
        return puzzles[difficulty][level];
    }else{
        console.warn("That puzzle doesn't exist!");
        return;
    }
}
```

We can now do something like `var puzzle = getPuzzle('hard', 2)`, but let's build on that and make a function that will get a random puzzle.

```
function getRandomPuzzle(level) {
  return getPuzzle(level, Math.floor(Math.random() * (puzzles[level].length)));
}

var puzzle = getRandomPuzzle('hard');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `eval` Javascript function.

`var puzzle = eval('level_' + get_level + '_puzzle_' + get_puzzle);`

This will give you your puzzle.

Comment: I'll be back to try out your answer

Comment: Using *eval* is not a particularly good answer, it's the `GOTO` of javascript. If the variables are global, then `windw['level_' + get_level + '_puzzle_' + get_puzzle]` would be preferred, or better would be object properties.

Comment: @RobG I personally don't want to advocate for `eval`, however from the way the OP asked his question it seemed to be the only answer. I personally like Chad's answer (above) better, however (strictly speaking) it does modify the question to the answer. In addition, global variables are typically discouraged, and using object properties would probably force you to modify the question.

Comment: @boboman13: Doesn't OP mean organic programming? I looked it up and I don't understand what it means

Comment: @boboman13: eval() worked, but I'm going to try to do Chad's answer because it seems cleaner.

Comment: @codeshackel OP means original poster. Good choice, I like Chad's answer better anyways.